# Print x amount QR codes each with a unique ID

Tags: printer, barcode-scanner

This is hardware/software question.

Is there a label printer that allows me to configure it so that instead of creating each label individually I am able to set it to start from the ID 1000 and increment automatically and print until the unique ID has hit 2000?

Would prefer the cheapest printer available however the budget is £500; if it exceeds the budget still please let me know.